# border-color property works as style, not as css class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure this is a simple problem, but I can't seem to get a css class to work. I'm trying to add a red border around a text input. If I set the border-color property inline, everything works:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder ="Name" style="border-color: #b94a48;" />
```

If I add a class to the surrounding div, targeting inputs, it works correctly:

```
.error-style input {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #b94a48;
}

<div class="control-group error-style">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" placeholder ="Name"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

But if I just make it a class, and add it to the input, it doesn't show:

```
.error-style {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #b94a48;
}

<input type="text" placeholder ="Name" class="error-style" />
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm also using Twitter Bootstrap in the project. The CSS file for Bootstrap can be found [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bootstrap.css **line no 1013** it is making your input border color grey

to solve that use following css

```
.controls .error-style{border-style:solid;border-color: #b94a48;}
```

This way you are making high precedence value for this class. This way is far better than using !important.

I hope it clear your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

A width is required for the border. If that doesn't work, try applying **importance** to your CSS class as there may be something in the other CSS overriding it:

```
.error-style {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48 !important;
}

<input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="error-style" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a width:

```
.error-style input {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #b94a48;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

or simply:

```
.error-style input {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, but it isn't the width, it was a conflict with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
.error-style
    {
        border:2px solid #b94a48;
    }

<input type="text" placeholder ="Name" class="error-style" />
```

You can change the widht of border as per your requirement.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but it isn't the width, it was a conflict with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

you should write like mentioned below style and its working fine...

**CSS**

```
.error-style {
      border:2px solid #b94a48;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="error-style" />
```

**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/pGqegwmr)**

Comment: Appreciate the response, but it isn't the width, it was a conflict with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the source to bootstrap.css file before the source to your custom css.

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="yourCustom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

//yourCustom.css

```
.error-style {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48 !important;
}
```

CSS rendering is cascading. The values provided latest are applied to the elements. The new values will not work only in case the old values are marked as !important.